# How to change display from another function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, firebase-realtime-database

I have something in react native like this:

```js
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
    function startGenerate(exercises) {
        console.log(exercises);
            return (
                <View style = {global.container}>
                    <Button 
                        title = "Generate recommended exercises"
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('List', {exercises: exercises})}
                    />
                </View>
            )
    }
   

    var exercises = [];

    if (severityValue >= 7) {
        return (
            <View style = {global.container}>
                <Text>Test</Text>
            </View>
        )
    } else if (severityValue!=null) {
        writePainProfile(areaValue, typeValue, severityValue);
        onValue(ref(db, 'count'), (snapshot) => {
            const count = snapshot.val();
            exercises = filter(count);
            return (startGenerate(exercises));
        })
        //Calling exercises here returns an empty array
    } 
//...other code omitted here for brevity

}

export default HomeScreen
```

With the `onValue`, I'm reading a firebase realtime database, and then calling the filter function, which returns a list of filtered data that fit the specified criteria. I then want to create a page that displays the filtered data and I've attempted to do this through the `startGenerate` function, however nothing appears to be rendering. So, is there any better way to do this?

I've also noticed that attempting to use `exercises` outside the `onValue` returns an empty array, likely due to the way the `onValue` works, which significantly complicates things.

Edit:
Here's how the exercises array is formatted, as an Array of objects
[image]

And here's how I am attempting to render elements of the exercises array:

```js
return (
        <View style={global.container}>
        {exercises.map(exercise => {
            return <Text>----</Text>
        })};
        </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing is rendering is that updating a local variable `var exercises = [];` will not trigger a re-render in React. As `onValue` takes in a callback so it is async. We must update the state once the callback fires to trigger the re-render. Also please keep in mind that local variables are not permanent between re renders and functions called in a components body will fire on every render so you could end calling `onValue` more times than expected unless you use `useEffect. Instead, the way to achieve this would be to use React hooks to hold and set state. Please see example below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [exercises, setExercises] = React.useState([]);
  // this is called on mount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // running side effects
    writePainProfile(areaValue, typeValue, severityValue);
    onValue(ref(db, 'count'), (snapshot) => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      // update state
      setExercises(filter(count));
    });
  }, []);

  if (severityValue >= 7) {
    return (
      <View style={global.container}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  // if no exercises yet display a placeholder
  if (!(exercises?.length > 0)) {
    return (
      <View style={global.container}>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View style={global.container}>
      <Button
        title="Generate recommended exercises"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('List', { exercises: exercises })}
      />
      // this should work for the provided format
     {exercises.map((exercise) => {
      return <Text>{exercise.name}</Text>;
     })}
    </View>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much. If I were to display the contents of the exercises array in this function though, how would I go about doing that? I have tried `exercises.map` but that is not rendering anything

Comment: @RenaW I updated my answer. Also fixed flawed logic here`if (!(exercises?.length > 0)) {` Please let me know if that works

Comment: Yes, getting the exercises array worked as normal, however `exercises` is an array of objects obtained from firebase, I tried `return <Text>{exercise.name}</Text>`, which isn't displaying anything (I also updated my answer with how the exercises array is formatted)

Comment: @RenaW I updated my answer. `exercise.name` should  work so long as it matches the callback's argument

Comment: odd, that is what I have in my code right now (see edit) but nothing is showing up, even when I have it display some random text the screen is still empty

Comment: @RenaW you have a semicolon `;` after the JSX curly braces. That will cause an exception `})};` remove that last semicolon and if everything was correct then it should render